# ORA-03001: unimplemented feature

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing this error ORA-00972: identifier is too long when executed the below script.

```
SELECT distinct
"   AMACADRAD_1.APP_PRTFL_ID                 ""Portfolio ID"""
",  AMCIDRCD_1.CI_LONG_DN                    ""Application Description"""
",  AMCIDRCD_1.CI_NM                         ""Application Name"""
"
```

Comment: (1) Please tag correctly.  Oracle errors come from Oracle.  (2) What part of the error do you not understand?  It seems very clear.  (3)  Why do you have double quotes everywhere?

Comment: If the double quotes are removed i get a error saying illegal zero length identifier

Comment: What client do you use to run this? What is the point of `""` at the end of each line in the projection?

Comment: @APC Just a speculation, but the OP's query looks like a fragment of a Java SQL query string, with double quoted identifiers not correctly escaped.  Obviously, it won't run, and your answer is a good guess +1.

Comment: @APC oracle sql developer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and include the **rest of the query**. This query has five table names or (most likely) aliases (AMCIDRCD_1, AMCSDRHMLCD_1, AMIAOAODRAGOHD_2, AMCSDRHMLCD_3, and AASDDRAASD_1) which are not defined in the query. Thanks.

Comment: That query fragment makes no sense, please **[edit]** your question and add the **complete** statement. Also: which Oracle version are you using? You can see that with e.g. `select banner from v$version`

Answer (score 4):

In SQL double-quotes act to define identifiers. They are optional but if included they will change the nature of what is a valid character in a name. For instance `_EMP` is not a valid table name but `"_EMP"` is.

If you consider your query, everything is bounded in double-quotes, which means everything is treated as an identifier. This string is 44 characters long (including spaces)...

```
"   AMACADRAD_1.APP_PRTFL_ID                 "
```

... and that's why Oracle hurls ORA-00972.

Also it's highly unlikely that you have columns called things like ...

```
",  to_char(AMCIDRCD_1.SRC_SYS_UPD_DT,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')      "
```

... so your query will fail on ORA-00904 too.

Fortunately the solution is quite simple: just get rid of the double-quotes. Well, keep them if you really need column aliases with spaces, like `"Application Description"`. But remove all the others.

So that means your query ought to look something like this:

```
SELECT distinct
 AMACADRAD_1.APP_PRTFL_ID                 "Portfolio ID"
,  AMCIDRCD_1.CI_LONG_DN                    "Application Description"
,  AMCIDRCD_1.CI_NM                         "Application Name"
,  decode(( AMCSDRHMLCD_1.MSTR_L_COL_ID ),'ML_CI_STAT_KY',( AMCSDRHMLCD_1.DSPLY_DN ),'does not apply',( AMCSDRHMLCD_1.DSPLY_DN ),'not found',( AMCSDRHMLCD_1.DSPLY_DN ),'not avail',( AMCSDRHMLCD_1.DSPLY_DN ))   "Status Description"
,  AMIAOAODRAGOHD_2.ASGN_GRP_ORG_LVL_2_NM   "Biz Asset Owner Level 2 Name"
,  AMCIDRCD_1.BUS_OWN_EMAIL_NM_LIST_TX      "Bus Owner Email"
,  AMCIDRCD_1.IT_ASSET_OWN_CNTCT_TX         "IT Owner Email Address" 
,  decode(( AMCSDRHMLCD_3.MSTR_L_COL_ID ),'ML_DATA_CLS_KY',( AMCSDRHMLCD_3.DSPLY_DN ),'does not apply',( AMCSDRHMLCD_3.DSPLY_DN ),'not found',( AMCSDRHMLCD_3.DSPLY_DN ),'not avail',( AMCSDRHMLCD_3.DSPLY_DN ))   "Data Class"
,  decode(( AASDDRAASD_1.MSTR_L_COL_ID ),'ML_CI_CRTCLTY_KY',( AASDDRAASD_1.DSPLY_DN ),'does not apply',( AASDDRAASD_1.DSPLY_DN ),'not found',( AASDDRAASD_1.DSPLY_DN ),'not avail',( AASDDRAASD_1.DSPLY_DN ))   "Business Criticality"
,  to_char(AMCIDRCD_1.SRC_SYS_UPD_DT,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')      "CI Updated"

FROM ITR23.APP_CI_DTL_F adf
inner join ITR23.APP_D  AMACADRAD_1
on  AMACADRAD_1.app_ky = adf.app_ky
```

Those DECODE() statements look wrong, I can't guess what you're trying to do with them.

Comment: The OP's select statement does not appear to be a single doubly quoted term, and I get `ORA-00936: missing expression` when running it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - interesting. I tried running in on db<>fiddle and got `ORA-03001: unimplemented feature` so I'm just guessing.

Comment: @sonikasonu - if this answer helped you please consider accepting it. Accepted answers improve the value of this site as a resource for future Seekers.